# Facebook Graph API Insights values discrepancy

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I am using the Graph API to get data from facebook but I found strange that depending on the period chosen the values don't make sense to me.

the request

```
 /insights/page_impressions_unique?since=1432191600&until=1433401200
```

returns the following values:

```
  "name": "page_impressions_unique", 
      "period": "day", 
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 2, 
          "end_time": "2015-05-22T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 8, 
          "end_time": "2015-05-23T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 4, 
          "end_time": "2015-05-24T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 2, 
          "end_time": "2015-05-25T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2015-05-26T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 2, 
          "end_time": "2015-05-27T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 10, 
          "end_time": "2015-05-28T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 14, 
          "end_time": "2015-05-29T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 4, 
          "end_time": "2015-05-30T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 1, 
          "end_time": "2015-05-31T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 1, 
          "end_time": "2015-06-01T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 3, 
          "end_time": "2015-06-02T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 108, 
          "end_time": "2015-06-03T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 17, 
          "end_time": "2015-06-04T07:00:00+0000"
        }
      ], 
      "title": "Daily Total Reach", 
      "description": "Daily: The number of people who have seen any content associated with your Page. (Unique Users)"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "page_impressions_unique", 
      "period": "week", 
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 110, 
          "end_time": "2015-05-22T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 114, 
          "end_time": "2015-05-23T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 116, 
          "end_time": "2015-05-24T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 116, 
          "end_time": "2015-05-25T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 69, 
          "end_time": "2015-05-26T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 16, 
          "end_time": "2015-05-27T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 20, 
          "end_time": "2015-05-28T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 29, 
          "end_time": "2015-05-29T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 27, 
          "end_time": "2015-05-30T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 24, 
          "end_time": "2015-05-31T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 23, 
          "end_time": "2015-06-01T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 23, 
          "end_time": "2015-06-02T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 125, 
          "end_time": "2015-06-03T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 131, 
          "end_time": "2015-06-04T07:00:00+0000"
        }
      ],
```

I know the **"period": "week"** values are the SUM of the 7 days prior to the end_time, but I can't get to those values by adding the days in the **"period": "day"** .

TL;DR: does anyone know how to get the week values by adding the day values?

Comment: These are unique impressions so a week's data for unique impressions will be lesser than the sum of the 7 days of the week. It would be equal in the case when there're no duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

This is because when you ask for week it gives you weekly data means, for `"end_time": "2015-05-22T07:00:00+0000"` the data is for last 7 days i.e. it consist data of `"2015-05-16T07:00:00+0000"` to `"2015-05-22T07:00:00+0000"` and for `"end_time": "2015-05-23T07:00:00+0000"` the data is for last 7 days i.e. it consist data of `"2015-05-17T07:00:00+0000" to "2015-05-23T07:00:00+0000"`.

If you sum all the values from day period between this range then you can get the value greater than or equal to the value return by weekly data due to unique in the last 7 day.

You can also try with

```
 /insights/page_impressions_unique?since=1432191600&until=1432364400
```

then you will get weekly data but since is `"2015-05-21T07:00:00+0000" & until is "2015-05-23T07:00:00+0000"`, date range is for 2 days data but we will get weekly data for this as well.

Above Information is valid as the Facebook team, I got this answer from Facebook developers. We had the conversation with the Facebook team regarding the same problem we had in our application.